# How can I get the thread name (not lable)

Tags: multithreading, jmeter

How can I get the Thread Controller Name (i.e. 'Thread Group')?

In my test I have:
Thread Controller Name: 'Thread Group'
Thread Name: 'My Thread'

Thanks,

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take a look at the following [JMeter Functions](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/apache-jmeter-functions-introduction):

- [`__threadGroupName()`](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadGroupName) - returns the name of the Thread Group
- [`__threadNum()`](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__threadNum) - returns the number of the current thread

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the quick response. I know how to get the ThreadGroupName, what I'm looking for is the thread group controller name (i.e. Thread Group, Ultimate Thread Group...)

Comment: You can use [__groovy() function](https://jmeter.apache.org/usermanual/functions.html#__groovy), something like `${__groovy(def threadGroupClass = ctx.getThreadGroup().getProperty(org.apache.jmeter.testelement.TestElement.TEST_CLASS) as String; return threadGroupClass.substring(threadGroupClass.lastIndexOf('.') + 1),)}` should do the trick for you. In the above example `ctx` stands for JMeterContext, see [Top 8 JMeter Java Classes You Should Be Using with Groovy](https://www.blazemeter.com/blog/top-8-jmeter-java-classes-you-should-be-using-with-groovy) article for more details.

Comment: sorry for the delay :) thanks, the groovy function works fine